# How to edit a specific dictionary key inside of a list of dictionary

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I can't find a **specific** example how to achieve this:
I am trying to edit a specific dictionary in a list of dictionaries that I imported from Mongo. This is my current code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient as MC
server = MC("localhost", 27017)
db = server['SALARY']
collection = db['data']


import os
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')

try:
    server.server_info()
except:
    print("Could not connect to Mongo Database. Please see administrator.")
else:
    data_list = collection.find({})
    use_data = (list(data_list))
    for i in use_data:
        print(("First name:"), (i["first"])+",", 
              (" Last name:"),(i["last"])+",", 
              (" Salary:"),(i["salary"])+",", 
              (" Rate:"), (i["rate"]))
```

I need to add a `New_Salary` value to the dictionary. I figured out how to add it blank to every dictionary in the list:

```
    for item in use_data: item['New_Salary']='0'
```

Here's the output for the entire script, including adding the blank new_salary:

```
First name: Rachel,  Last name: D,  Salary: 10,000,  Rate: 0.3
First name: Tom,  Last name: Jackson,  Salary: 20,000,  Rate: 0.4
First name: Michael,  Last name: Doe,  Salary: 40,000,  Rate: 0.4
First name: Rose,  Last name: D,  Salary: 70,000,  Rate: 0.2
First name: Kailey,  Last name: Jole,  Salary: 30,000,  Rate: 0.6
First name: Catharine,  Last name: Park,  Salary: 35,000,  Rate: 0.5
First name: Polly,  Last name: Pocket,  Salary: 14,000,  Rate: 0.2
First name: John,  Last name: Jackson,  Salary: 12,000,  Rate: 0.4
[{'_id': ObjectId('626038518ff3b19db134bf7a'), 'first': 'Rachel', 'last': 'D', 'salary': '10,000', 'rate': '0.3', 'New_Salary': '0'}, {'_id': ObjectId('6260388a8ff3b19db134bf7c'), 'first': 'Tom', 'last': 'Jackson', 'salary': '20,000', 'rate': '0.4', 'New_Salary': '0'}, {'_id': ObjectId('626038f58ff3b19db134bf7e'), 'first': 'Michael', 'last': 'Doe', 'salary': '40,000', 'rate': '0.4', 'New_Salary': '0'}, {'_id': ObjectId('6260395e8ff3b19db134bf80'), 'first': 'Rose', 'last': 'D', 'salary': '70,000', 'rate': '0.2', 'New_Salary': '0'}, {'_id': ObjectId('6260399d8ff3b19db134bf82'), 'first': 'Kailey', 'last': 'Jole', 'salary': '30,000', 'rate': '0.6', 'New_Salary': '0'}, {'_id': ObjectId('626039be8ff3b19db134bf84'), 'first': 'Catharine', 'last': 'Park', 'salary': '35,000', 'rate': '0.5', 'New_Salary': '0'}, {'_id': ObjectId('626039cb8ff3b19db134bf85'), 'first': 'Polly', 'last': 'Pocket', 'salary': '14,000', 'rate': '0.2', 'New_Salary': '0'}, {'_id': ObjectId('626039dc8ff3b19db134bf86'), 'first': 'John', 'last': 'Jackson', 'salary': '12,000', 'rate': '0.4', 'New_Salary': '0'}]
```

What I don't yet know how to do is find the value of the `New_Salary` for each dictionary in the list. The value of should be equal to the current salary, plus a percentage of the current salary equal to the `rate` value. The salaries and rates for each dictionary are different.

Comment: `i['salary'] = float(i['salary'].replace(',', '')) * 0.3`

Comment: @Barmar THANK YOU! This is almost exactly what I need. What yours does is replace every new_salary in all the dictionaries with the entire value and puts: for example, 10,000 x 0.3 = 3000, it puts 3000 in the new_salary. Is there a way to keep the original salary and ADD the 3000? so the new salary would be 13,000 (in this example).

Every salary is different with different rates, so for example michael doe's salary is 40,000, with a rate of 0.4. So, 40,000 x 0.4 = 16,000. The new_salary for him would be 56,000.

Not sure if this is possible to loop and do for everyone though

Comment: Multiply by 1.3 instead of 0.3. This is basic math.

Comment: @Barmar I actually just did this before I replied, and I thought it was exactly what I needed, the only thing is it puts a rate of 0.3 for everyone, My bad if I explained it in a confusing way, it's kind of hard to explain. Is there a way to make this code so that it takes the specific rates from every dictionary?

I was trying to say how every person has a different rate, so not everyones is 0.3, the code is absolutely perfect if they all were.

Comment: @RachelD please,  i['salary'] = float(i['salary'].replace(',', '')) * (1+i['rate'])

Comment: @dasfacc thanks, it worked! sorry if my comments were a bit confusing

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a helper for this. It will really help you parse out into a readable form exactly what you're doing. Notably this copies your list of dictionaries, but for most applications that will be fine.

```
from print import pprint
def process_employee(emp: dict) -> dict:
    rate = emp.get("rate", 0.0)
    current_salary = emp.get("salary", "0")
    # Add 1 to rate to make the multiplication calculate the rise and add it in.
    # Replace the commas in salary to treat it as a number that allows multiplication.
    new_salary = (rate + 1.0) * float(current_salary.replace(",", ""))
    return {
        "_id": emp.get("_id"),
        "first": emp.get("first"),
        "name": emp.get("last"),
        "salary": current_salary,
        "rate": rate
        "new_salary": new_salary,
    }


data_list = collection.find({})
processed_list = [process_employee(e) for e in list(data_list)]
pprint(processed_list)  # You already know how to print each item, this is just a quick way to see a human-readable list of dicts.
```

Essentially, you have two parts of the problem:

1. Add a new value for each dictionary in the list.
2. Calculate that value.

Rather than deal with it as a list, consider only a single dictionary. Given an input dictionary, figure out how to output the dictionary you want.

For calculating the value, we lean on math a little. A rate of `.3` is "thirty percent of the original". So we know if we want the original plus this, we want "one hundred percent of the original plus thirty percent - a hundred and thirty percent of the original." This is equivalent to `1.3` - just adding `1` gets us this.

By using a helper function we can tease out these little parts and make sure we're assembling our output correctly. Then it's just a matter of using our helper in a loop over all the dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer, I am just getting an error here: `def process_employee(emp: dict) -> dict {  SyntaxError: invalid syntax`  (It points at the first { and I'm not exactly sure how to fix this, also, had to rewrite my comment because I included something I wrote to try and fix it and couldn't edit lol, so sorry if you got 2 notifs)

Comment: @RachelD Sorry! I had context-switched in from golang. The issue was that there should be a colon `:` after `-> dict`, not an open brace. I've fixed the code in the answer.